# Can I enter a Schengen country with a non-Schengen Irish visa-D?

Tags: transit, international-travel, self-transfer

I have an Irish (non-Schengen) visa-D (multiple-entry). Can I enter Schengen countries?

I plan to fly to Ireland for the first time, through Italy or Austria,  but the flight is with a long transit time and self transfer. Do I need an additional Schengen visa for those countries?

Answer (score 4):

> I have a Irish (non-Schengen) visa-D (multi-entry) can I enter Schengen countries?

No, you cannot, at least not on the basis of this visa.

> I plan to fly to Ireland for the first time, through Italy or Austria but the flight is with long transit time and self transfer, do I need additional Schengen visa for those country?

Since you cannot enter the Schengen area on foot of an Irish D visa, you will need a separate Schengen short-stay visa for this transfer.

Comment: On foot of? Error?

Comment: @Willeke No, it's Irish legal English and a phrase I picked up living in Ireland ages ago long before I realised it wasn't used elsewhere.

Comment: Incidentally, I think I have used it before on SE and it has never been so appropriate!

Comment: In this context: [On foot of an Irish idiom | Sentence first](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2017/08/14/on-foot-of-an-irish-idiom/): *on the basis of*